# Invalid callback error in Remote Ajax call using JSONP

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, remote-access, cross-site

I am in a web programming class and trying to figure out how to make a cross-site request to use the taxifarefinder API. I am using Google Chrome's Developer tools. When I run the code below, I get the right response (Shown after code block).
However, I need to be able to pass in different parameters for origin and destination in the csCall variable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Working Echo Client</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script>

    function jsonp(url) {
        var head = document.head;
        var script = document.createElement("script");

        script.setAttribute("src", url);
        console.log(script);
        head.appendChild(script);
        head.removeChild(script);
    }

    function jsonpCallback(data) {
        document.getElementById("response").textContent = JSON.stringify(data);
    }

    var csCall ="http://api.taxifarefinder.com/fare?key=mUnes8afrE3a&entity_handle=Boston&origin=42,-71&destination=42,-71.5&callback=jsonpCallback"
jsonp(csCall);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <span id="response"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Response:Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://api.taxifarefinder.com/fare?key=mUnes8afrE3a&entity_handle=Boston&origin=-41,-71&destination=-41,-71.5&callback=jsonpCallback".

This displays accurately on the page: {"status":"OK","total_fare":7.69,"initial_fare":2.6,...,"distance":1849,"duration":232}

So I then tried to create a function to take in the longitudes and latitudes that make up the origin and destination parameters and make the call but when I try it, I get the error message following the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Working Echo Client</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script>

    function jsonp(url) {
        var head = document.head;
        var script = document.createElement("script");

        script.setAttribute("src", url);
        head.appendChild(script);
        head.removeChild(script);
    }

    function jsonpCallback(data) {
        document.getElementById("response").textContent = data;
    }

    function makeCall(oLat, oLon, dLat, dLon) {
        var oLat = parseFloat(oLat);
        var oLon = parseFloat(oLon);
        var dLat = parseFloat(dLat);
        var dLon = parseFloat(dLon);

        csCall = "http://api.taxifarefinder.com/fare?key=mUnes8afrE3a&entity_handle=Boston&origin=" + oLat + "," + oLon + "&destination=" + dLat + "," + dLon + "&callback=" + jsonpCallback;
    }

    var csCall;
    makeCall(-42, 71, -42, 71.5);
    jsonp(csCall);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <span id="response"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Response on the console: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://api.taxifarefinder.com/fare?key=mUnes8afrE3a&entity_handle=Boston&or…lementById(%22response%22).textContent%20=%20data;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20}".

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :    fare:1
When I click on fare:1 I am redirected to the sources tab where I see this:
{"status":"INVALID_CALLBACK"}.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong which could be causing the invalid callback? The only change I see is the addition of a function to concatenate the uri.

Answer (score 0):

Appending a function to a string is the same as calling the `toString` method of the function, which returns the functions code. What you actually what to do is, to append the callback's name.

```js
"http://api.taxifarefinder.com/fare?key=...&entity_handle=Boston"
+ "&origin=" + oLat + "," + oLon 
+ "&destination=" + dLat + "," + dLon 
+ "&callback=jsonpCallback";
```

Also, be sure that the callback is in the global namespace, as else the script-injected code won't be able to find and call it.